Texas HB 1181: How does jurisdiction work?
Texas HB 1181 requires commercial sites that serve more than 1/3 of their content as porn to verify users from Texas prior to serving them explicit material or face civil penalties. Can someone please explain how jurisdiction of this works to me?
If I live in Florida and operate a site via a virtual machine hosted in San Francisco, why would a Texas state law apply to me?
The only rational I can think of is that it is because I am transmitting data which ultimately arrives in Texas. But the requesting user, despite living in Texas, actually has to send physical data out of the state to me in order to receive a response.
How could Texas fine me if I don't live there?

Mostly about how a Texas state court could even have jurisdiction over a party when that party doesn't do business within the state. I was struggling to find any info on it when searching specific to HB1181. I have since found articles that say it is possible because courts can interpret any interactivity on a website as an attempt to further business with residents from whichever jurisdiction they reside (Heroes, Inc. v. Heros Foundation). And sometimes just based on site visitors (Minnesota v. Granite Gate Resorts). https://cyber.harvard.edu/property99/domain/Betsy.html

Based on my above comment, I will assume a TX court could sue someone that doesn't live there for operating a website. Can you please enlighten me as to how enforcement would work? Can they garnish my non TX assets or would I just have to avoid the state?

As a general law principle: if you and your business are located in state/ country A and your customer is in state/ country B then both the laws in A and B are relevant for your transaction. The details especially with conflicting laws can be complicated and enforcement can be messy but you can't simply ignore the laws in B because you are in A.

A news report on the law in question is here. The final bill text is here.
The legal standard for long arm jurisdiction in civil cases in this kind of situation, is purposeful availment of the laws of the state by doing business directed at the residents of the state.
If an out of state website has paying or registered customers in the state, it probably meets the requirements for being subject to the "long arm jurisdiction" of the state's courts with respect to those paying or registered customers, at least. A physical presence in the state is not required, if the jurisdiction-creating facts are related to the lawsuit in question. The website would also be subject to state sales taxes under current U.S. law for what it charges its paying customers.
In this case, in the context of someone who clicks on a porn site not directed at Texas specifically in any way, who does not register with the site or provide any payment to the site, the outcome under the relevant legal tests is really in a gray area. It could reasonably be resolved either way on the jurisdiction question under current U.S. legal precedents.
From the comments:

Can you please enlighten me as to how enforcement would work? Can they
garnish my non TX assets or would I just have to avoid the state?

In the case of a defendant who has assets or income in the United States, Texas can have its money judgment for a fine from its courts recognized a registered in any other U.S. state under the Full Faith and Credit clause of the United States Constitution (i.e. Article IV, Section 1) and enforce the judgment in the state in which the assets or income is located.
In the case of a foreign porn website, that would often be a U.S. banking institution that collects payments from paying customers. In the case of a domestic porn website, that all of the company's assets and income would usually be U.S. based.
The jurisdiction of the Texas courts to enter that judgment could be collaterally attacked in the enforcement proceeding if the jurisdiction issue was not litigated in the original Texas case and the judgment entered by default instead. But the merits can't be argued in the collateral attack if you lose. If you lose the jurisdiction issue in a collateral attack, you can't attack the merits of the claim (e.g. the facts, or the validity of the law enforced).

I'm no lawyer, but in reading the text of the bill, I can't see anything that states that the porn sites need to comply with the bill only if they are supply content to residents of Texas.  This may be my not understanding what I am reading, but it seems like it could be directed at any porn provider anywhere.  Also, the Houston Chronicle article appears pay-walled to me because I have an ad blocker.

@PeterM In the absence of a clearly expressed intent to the contrary laws only apply in the territory of the body passing the legislation (i.e. to interactions with Texas internet users). Texas would clearly lack jurisdiction, as a constitutional matter, over an interaction between, e.g., a California porn website operator and a Minnesota internet user.

OK I'll go with that, but it's a fine line given that Texas is trying to enforce Texan laws against Texans who get medical procedures outside of Texas.

@PeterM Those laws will generally expressly state their extraterritorial claimed application and even then, they don't purport to apply to people from say, Alabama, who get medical procedures in Colorado.

@ohwilleke Fantastic answer. Thank you very much.

@PeterM In that case, I believe they're criminalizing the act of leaving the state for the purpose of getting the procedure. Theoretically they could have similar laws that criminalize leaving the state to rob a bank in another state, but there isn't as much political need for that (there are no states that allow bank robbery).
